# How to add multiple lines to the beginning of many files in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a file beginning.txt that contains lines like:

```
Disclaimer Here
This is a Notice
I have something liere
```

How can I execute a linux command to add all the lines in beginning.txt to the top of each file that matches the extension ".customfile" (note that .customfile is just a textfile, but these files may be within subdirectories within my current folder that i also want updated)?

I have many files with the .customfile suffix that I want to append, so looking for a way to do this programatically. I see example with sed command that appear limited to a single line.

```
sed -i '1s/^/<added text> /' file
```

Comment: You can add them in a new file and then rename the file.

Comment: I have a lot of different files, want to do this via command line using something like sed

Comment: `man sed` and look for `r` (read). Good luck.

Comment: @Rolando, check out my solution using pure `sed`, and `find` coupled with `xargs` in searching the current directory for `*.customfile`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450224/insert-copyright-message-into-multiple-files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With bash:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.customfile"); do
  echo Processing $file

  cat beginning.txt $file > $file.modified

  mv $file.modified $file

done
```

Comment: Using `cat` for its intended purpose, that's a refreshing change. Only nit would be to create the temp file in system tempdir (if set), otherwise in `/tmp`. Something like `[ -n "$TMPDIR" ] && tmpdir="$TMPDIR"; [ -z "$TMPDIR" -a -d "/tmp" ] && tmpdir=/tmp`

Comment: Very useful! Do you know why the order of processing doesn't follow the filename order?

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` command `r` is pretty useful in appending contents of a file at certain location, except when that location is line 0.

Inserting your text before line 1 is like appending after line 0. It would've been the solution if `sed '0r /path/to/beginning.txt *.customfile` was allowed.

You can use process substitution along with `sed`. The process substitution will generate a `sed` command that can be run against any files you searched for.

```
sed -i -f - file < <(sed 's/^/1i/' /path/to/beginning.txt)
```

The process `sed 's/^/1i/' /path/to/beginning.txt` will generate `sed` commands to insert the texts found in `/path/to/beginning.txt`:

```
1iDisclaimer Here
1iThis is a Notice
1iI have something liere
```

`sed -f -` will read the sed command from a file, `-` means the file is `stdin`.

If you need to run it on multiple files, you can either use globs or `find` and `xargs`.

Sample using multiple files:

```
sed -i -f - /path/to/*.customfile < <(sed 's/^/1i/' /path/to/beginning.txt)
```

Sample using find and xargs:

```
find . -type f -name \*.customfile | xargs -I{} bash -c "sed -f - {} < <(sed 's/^/1i/' /tmp/beginning.txt)"
```

Alternatively, you can avoid re-running `sed 's/^/1i/' /path/to/beginning.txt` for every file by assigning the output to a variable and using here string to pass to the `sed` command.

```
sedcommand=$(sed 's/^/1i/' /path/to/beginning.txt)
sed -i -f - /path/to/*.customfile <<< "$sedcommand"
```

Or create a `command.sed` file from `beginning.txt` and use it to insert the texts to your custom files.

```
sed 's/^/1i/' /path/to/beginning.txt > /path/to/command.sed
sed -i -f /path/to/command.sed /path/to/*.customfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started, you will just need to tweak it to your liking:

```
for i in *.customfile; do  sed -i '1s/^/<your_text> \n/' $i; done
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to leave the multi-line text in a file, and just have the one line command read the contents/"your_text" from the file to append to the beginning of each file?

Comment: Getting error; sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try something like this

```
find . -name "*.customfile" -type f | while read i; do cat beginning.txt $i | tee $i 1>/dev/null ; done
```

Maybe not the most elegant use of the tee command, but it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic problems:

1. Find all the files to change (`*.customfile`)
2. Add the lines to the beginning of the existing file

#1 can be solved easily with `find`.
#2 is probably easiest to do by adding the lines to a temporary file, then moving files around.

Here is a one-line shell command that will do it, assuming that you have the lines you want to add in a file called `beginning.txt`:

`find . -name "*.customfile" -print | while read fn ; do echo fixing $fn ; cat beginning.txt "$fn" > "$fn".new && mv "$fn" "$fn".old && mv "$fn".new "$fn" ; done`

Answer (score 0):

While `cat` is the proper shell tool for the job (see: Robert's answer, which I would suggest instead), if you do want to torment yourself with a multi-line substitution or insert of the disclaimer text at the beginning of a large number of files, you can use the **Address** prefix for `sed` to locate the first beginning of a line, and then execute the substitution with `sed` replacing the beginning of the first line (e.g. beginning of file) using the *regex* `'^'` with your disclaimer text.

Specifically, you would be using the `'0,addr2'` form of the **Address** for `sed` where if `addr2` (a *regex*) matches the first line of input it causes the `0,addr2` form to be at its end of range and to substitute (insert) the replacement text once and quit.

For example, to add your disclaimer at the beginning of each file in `files` (whether you use globbing or `find` with *process-substitution* to select the desired files) would take the form:

```
## set disclaimer text in `dc` however you like
dc='Disclaimer Here\nThis is a Notice\nI have something liere\n'

## use 0,addr2 Address form to insert at beginning of each file.
sed -i "0,/^/s/^/${dc}/" files
```

**Example File**

```
$ cat dat/basefile.txt
========
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog.
```

**Example Use/Output (to stdout for example**

```
$ dc='Disclaimer Here\nThis is a Notice\nI have something liere\n' \
sed -e "0,/^/s/^/${dc}/" dat/basefile.txt
Disclaimer Here
This is a Notice
I have something liere
========
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Rather than torment yourself, use `cat` instead...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another small solution without a tmp-File (Only the beginning text is in one file)

```
for i in `ls *.customfile`; do echo -e "`cat prepend.txt`$(cat $i)" > $i; done
```

If you don't want the file *prepend.txt* you can replace the cat-command with lines with a "\n" after the text.